# How do I pass a user input value to an image src using jinja2 templating in Flask?

Tags: html, flask, input, jinja2

This input dropdown menu allows a user to select the number of products they would like to purchase:

```
<input type="number" id="shopdrop1" value="1" min="1" max="1000" step="1">
```

The following modal dialogue returns a QR code from the backend flask route:

```
<div id="product1" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="back">X</a>
        <br><img id="qrcode1" src="{{ url_for('qr',id="01",price=10) }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

So, my question is how can I append the `img src` with the value of the user input? To illustrate, in an ideal world it should be something like this:

```
<img id="qrcode1" src="{{ url_for('qr',id="01",price=10,num=shopdrop1.value) }}">
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: so you want to append the img path in src through user input?

Comment: to manipulate the client html you need to use javascript

Comment: @Umair Yes if possible?